# Screenshot open select element crashes mouse interaction with ubuntu's UI

Tags: gnome, mouse, chromium, screenshot, brave

How to replicate:

1. Open a select element on a website
2. Try to take a screenshot using Ctrl + Shift + PrtSc
3. Try to use your mouse to do anything else except for the browser window

You cannot switch applications using your mouse. You cannot do anything with your mouse except in that browser process.

I am 90% certain that this is the same case with all browsers.

The only fix I found was rebooting the system.

My system:

- Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
- Brave Version 1.29.77 Chromium: 93.0.4577.63 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: It is absolutely expected. Use sceenshot with delay.

Comment: @N0rbert Can you clarify?

Comment: Printscreen does not work with drop down menu opened. It does not depend on web-browser, it is actual for every application.

Comment: @N0rbert Okay, so it is a bug? Its not normal your hole system stops working. On windows it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is normal, not a bug but feature.
You can use a workaround - run screenshot tool interactively and specify timeout in it:

- GNOME - `gnome-screenshot -i`
- MATE - `mate-screenshot -i`

Comment: How can it be a feature your system crashes?

Comment: Please share a screencast of crash.